# Parameter of Array type in ARM Template

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have an ARM Template with a parameter of array type as follows:

[image]

How do I set values in 2nd and 3rd position of parameter array? (for instance, "b", "c" in this example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** Directly using the array index -

You can use the values of Array parameter by using this expression:

For 1st value: `"[parameters('parameter1')[0]]"`

For 2nd value: `"[parameters('parameter1')[1]]"`

For 3rd value: `"[parameters('parameter1')[2]]"`

You can test this sample template for fetching the values from array and displaying in the output:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "parameter1": {
            "defaultValue": [
                "value1",
                "value2",
                "value3"
            ],
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "firstValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('parameter1')[0]]"
        },
        "secondValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('parameter1')[1]]"
        },
        "thirdValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('parameter1')[2]]"
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

**Method 2:** If you want to use **copyIndex**. Use the below expression -

```
"[parameters('parameter1')[copyIndex()]]"
```

Please check the below example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "parameter1": {
            "defaultValue": [
                "strvalue1",
                "strvalue2"
            ],
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('parameter1')[copyIndex()]]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {},
            "copy": {
                "name": "storagecopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('parameter1'))]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to loop using ‘copy’ and get index positions instead of hardcoding 0, 1, 2?

Comment: @user989988 Check the update in the answer. Hope this helps!